# jquery parent child click event handling

Tags: jquery, click, parent, stoppropagation

I have a table row with 2 columns that I add dynamically (below).

```
var lientry='<tr id=\"'+kmlFeatureData.type+kmlFeatureData.id+'\">
<td>blah blah</td>
<td><a class="msg_head">'+'click for more</a></td></tr>';
```

I have a click handler for the first column id=...  which works fine, and I would like to have a second click handler for the second column class="msg_head", but when I try to catch it, it only calls the parent  handler.

I have tried suggestions, such as stopping propagation, with no luck.

```
$(".msg_head a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('jquery msg_head click');
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated post to show code. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'it only calls the parent handler'?

Comment: Are you adding the rows after assigning the event handler? Then you need to delegate the event using `.on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. Use `a.msg_head` instead:

```
$("a.msg_head").click(function(e) {
    alert('jquery msg_head click');
});
```

Or just get rid of the tag selector, and use `$(".msg_head")`.